# Google Data Studio: blend 3 data sources with 2 different keys

Tags: blending, looker-studio

I am currently creating a marketing dashboard with 3 data sources: Google Ads (Adwords), Redshift and a Google Sheet.

I am facing an issue when it comes to blend those 3 data sources
with 2 different keys.

I hereby mean blending:

1. Adwords with Sheets thanks to a first key
2. Sheets with Redshift thanks to a second key

So that I end up with a table combining these 3 data sources.

Do you guys have a solution to bypass Data Studio's limitation to 1 key for the blending?

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently supported (as of Aug 20, 2018).

You can blend multiple data sources using the same (composite) key. For your example, you will need to do one of the mapping off the platform. You can request this as a feature on the [official Data Studio feature request tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=196095&template=0).